# SQL Server Reporting Service: Is configuration for these area of SSRS be scripted

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I am trying to automated the full installation of SSRS via scripting. I have been able to cover all areas using RSConfig except the following:

- Web Service URL: In SSRS UI configuration page accept the defaults and press apply
- Change Database: In SSRS UI configuration page I choose change database and enter appropriate values

Any directions appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For Automating the WebService Url configuration What I have done is use PowerShell to create a Self-Signed certificate and use following script to bind the Certificate for Secure HTTPS weblink.

$serverClass = get-wmiobject -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_SSRS\v15\Admin" -class "MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"

ConfigureSSRSCertificate "https://$($NewHostNameForCertificate):$SSLPortNumber" $Thumbprint $SSLPortNumber

function ConfigureSSRSCertificate($sslURL, $certHash, $sslPort)
{
$certHash = $certHash.ToLower()
IISCertPortBinding
ReserveSSRSURL $sslUrl $LCID
CreateCertBinding $ReportServerWebService $certHash $sslPort $LCID
CreateCertBinding $ReportManager $certHash $sslPort $LCID
}

function IISCertPortBinding()
{
Get-WebBinding -Port $SSLPortNumber -Name "Default Web Site" | Remove-WebBinding
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$SSLPortNumber
}

function ReserveSSRSURL($sslUrl, $lcid)
{
[XML]$ReportConfigFileContent = Get-Content $ReportConfigFileContentPath
$URLItems = $ReportConfigFileContent.SelectNodes("//URL[UrlString='http://+:$PortNumber']")
foreach ($URLItem in $URLItems)
{
$NewURLItem = $URLItem.Clone()
$NewURLItem.UrlString = $sslUrl
$NewURLItem.AccountSid = "S-1-5-18"
$NewURLItem.AccountName = "LocalSystem"
$InsertAfterNode = $URLItem;
$URLItem.ParentNode.InsertAfter($NewURLItem,$InsertAfterNode)
}
$ReportConfigFileContent.save($ReportConfigFileContentPath)
}

function CreateCertBinding($ServiceOrReport, $certHash, $sslPort, $lcid)
{
$result = $serverClass.CreateSSLCertificateBinding($ServiceOrReport, $certHash, "0.0.0.0", $sslPort, $lcid)
}